# CAGradientLayer causes subviews not being visible

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

Hello Masters of iOS and Swift,

after two frustrating days, I desperately decided to ask here. The problem:

**When adding a CAGradientLayer, the subviews aren't shown.**

Details:

- I have made a method to add a CAGradientLayer in an extension of
  UIView
- I simply call the method on any view and this itself works perfectly
- But if I try to use this method for a UIView in a viewhierarchy (as a background) unfortunately all subviews aren't visible anymore, the
  gradient seems to "overrender" all subviews
- if I don't call the "addGradient" method on the container view, all subviews are shown properly
- amazing detail: Although the subviews aren't visible, they are somehow present and "active" (e.g. a "invisible" UIButton fires")
- I am using Autolayout

Any idea would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer and tried using the code added an imageView as subView worked fine for me. Have a look lemme know if it worked for you as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LukeSideWalker,

Not sure but you can always try to add your layer below all other layer so it wont cover existing subViews. Try this, in your extension where you add layer to view

```
self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
```

Tried adding ImageView as subView worked fine :) Should solve your problem as well.

Comment: @lukesidewalker : Surprizingly my first answer mentioned the same asking you to use below :) But when I tried running the code myself it din work . But specifying the index as 0 did the trick :)

Comment: try using "self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)" rather then addSublayer or insertSublayer(layer,below:___) see my updated answer :)

Comment: you saved my day ! :)))) -> I will accept this as the correct answer. I don't know why it works , BUT IT WORKS, if you by the way have an explanation it would be nice, just to understand not only implementing it. Thanks and have a great day too :)

Comment: @lukesidewalker : Am glad I could help buddy :) To be honest even I have no idea why below did not work :) In fact I tried using below with all possible permutation and combinations like adding subView first then layer, layer first then subView din work, finally had to use index 0 because it does what it says :) and fortunately worked :) Hope somebody who goes through the answer will be able to guide us as why it din work :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem before and resolved the issue by adding a background view to my view. So the view hierarchy would be like:

```
view
  backgroundView
  someView
    someViewInsideView
  someOtherView
```

Top views alpha seems to affect subview's alpha too. So I use a view with a clear background colour and use backgroundView to give view's background color and other property's with alpha modifiers.

Comment: Thanks Murat, I will try this, but at the moment I can not imagine how it should work, because the problem seems to be same, although another view is brought to the view hierarchy ...

Comment: As I understood the problem is when you modify the root view, all your subviews get effected by the same alpha modifiers. So your subviews don't show up correctly. What I'm suggesting is you should only modify the backgroundView (in this case add the gradient layer) and leave root view untouched. Other view's will not share any modifiers with backgroundView so they will be uneffected.

Comment: Again thanks, especially for your last explanation. As you can see Sandeep already gave me a perfect solution.